# Display the Number of Comment Upvotes In Recent Activity Pages

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page, user-interface, recent-activity

It would be helpful if we could see the number of upvotes cast for our comments, or other people's comments in response to us directly in the user profile in either the activity tab or the response tab respectively. It should be quite easy to implement (e.g. sharing a single partial view for displaying comments).

It could be useful, since we can evaluate the legitimacy of the comment and address horrible mistakes sooner.

Comment: Mimicking @Widor, has anything come of this? Is this [meta-tag:status-completed] (no, it's not), [meta-tag:status-declined], or [meta-tag:status-bydesign]? I realize this data is in data.SE, but at least one of the red tags here would be nice, considering the positive attention the question has had. :-)

Comment: I would also add ability to sort comments by these upvotes.

Comment: I keep having to click on each comment to see its score, this would be wonderful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like it'd be pretty simple since the data is already there.

I think it would let us review all comments at twice (both tabs), and see if we need to clean-up old or bad stuff.  I would also let people see how close they were to the `Pundit` badge.

Comment: FWIW, I think you'd be better off not having the information until you've got Pundit. Don't play for badges; play well, and let the badges come anyway.

Answer (score 11):

This would be a really useful feature - save a bit of time in following up on comments. I don't think it would actually be that hard to implement, as everybody already says, the data is already saved and freely available.

That said, here's a userscript to show the number of comment upvotes.

It adds a button next to each comment listing to show the score of it. I purposely haven't made it automatic because it would send way too many API requests in a short time and will probably cause you to get throttle violations every time you went on your profile!

It works for your comments (`all actions` tab > `comments`) and any responses (`responses` tab).

[image]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Show comment scores
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810
// @version      1.0
// @description  Shows your comment and comment reply scores in your profile page
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function() {
    var sitename = $(location).attr('hostname').split('.')[0];
    $('.history-table td b a').each(function() {
        id = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1].split('_')[0].replace('comment', '');
        $(this).after("<span class='showCommentScore' id='"+id+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;show comment score</span>");
    });    
    $('.showCommentScore').css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', function() {
        that = $(this);
        $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/" + that.attr('id') + "?order=desc&sort=creation&site=" + sitename, function(json) {
            that.html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + json.items[0].score);
        }); 
    });
}, 500);
```

This will be in the next version of my [SE Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features), and you can grab the development version (with this feature in it) over [here](https://github.com/shu8/SE_OptionalFeatures/tree/develop).

Comment: This looks like it might be a winner. I'll give it a couple weeks and see if we get anything internal, but failing that this will probably get the bounty. Either way, awesome work!

Answer (score 9):

Did/will anything ever come of this?

There's the 'Pundit' badge which requires 10 comments with a score of 5 - but without reviewing ALL our comments, it's hard to see if we're on track for example.

What about including it as a mouseover and sort option?

Comment: So long as you don't mind it being a month behind: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/945/my-top-ranked-comments

Comment: @agf Fantastic! And opened a whole new part of Stack' for me!

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a common request, with some duplicate questions asking for the same functionality. Posting new answer & bounty on the question to see if we can get it some much-needed love.

The data already exists in the system, and [we have a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/27196/my-top-ranked-comments) that will show the highest-ranked comments. What we're looking for, however, is a change to the UI that will show each comment's voting score directly on the Activity tab.