# Show question/answer/comment score in activity list

Tags: feature-request, score, activity

When viewing my activity I would like to see the score for each post (questions, answers, and even comments). This would help me get a pictures of how my recent posts have done without having to click through everything.

Comment: Is that easier than using the "Newest" sort in the user info page?

Comment: +1, thought the very same thing today. @mmyers: Yes, it tells me something about _comment_ votes.

Comment: See also [Display the Number of Comment Upvotes In Recent Activity Pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38285).