# In my user activity profile, could the comments display their score beside them?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, recent-activity, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display the Number of Comment Upvotes In Recent Activity Pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38285/display-the-number-of-comment-upvotes-in-recent-activity-pages)

It would make it much easier to track my progress toward the Pundit badge:

`Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more`

Note:  I'm not asking for any sorting abilities or anything fancy, just the number of comment up-votes.  :O)

Comment: This may not be likely to happen. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/101#101 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report

Comment: userscript over [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252985/260841)