# How to search score of comments

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-voting

Is there any where that give me the list of my comment sorted by its score descending or not sorted and just shows the score of that?

I think this result will guide me to write better comments in future.

Comment: I found this [quey](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/312179/my-top-comments) for that, but my question is about some where for all new users ;).

Comment: How does that query not answer your question? I don't understand what is missing/wrong with it?

Comment: @rene probably OP is after live data, not data that might be week old. So assuming I'm correct in my assumption, this is not possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard live data is coming from the API...

Comment: Unfortunately, the premise "this result will guide me to write better comments in future" is flawed. The comment score has little to do with quality, and a lot to do with tangential factors like the number of views on the question and the timing of the comment. I suggest not spending much time worrying about the quality of your comments: focus on the quality of your answers and questions.

Answer (score 8):

If you can't wait for a week for the comments to make it into SEDE you can use the [StackAPI](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users) that has an endpoint on the user for [comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users#order=desc&sort=votes&ids=4519059&filter=!mSGf9k.VVw&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

If you run that with the sort on `Votes`, sort order descending and the filter I created to also show the body of the comment this will be the output (partial) for you:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "edited": false,
      "score": 3,
      "creation_date": 1425879953,
      "post_id": 28935847,
      "comment_id": 46127080,
      "body_markdown": "Is there any relation between students and sites ?",
      "body": "Is there any relation between students and sites ?"
    },
    {
      "edited": false,
      "score": 3,
      "creation_date": 1430046231,
      "post_id": 29876645,
      "comment_id": 47877843,
      "body_markdown": "Please add more details and explanations for OP about why he or she needs your code ;).",
      "body": "Please add more details and explanations for OP about why he or she needs your code ;)."
    },
    {
      "edited": false,
      "score": 3,
      "creation_date": 1430975581,
      "post_id": 30092385,
      "comment_id": 48297398,
      "body_markdown": "`mi` is for minute ;).",
      "body": "<code>mi</code> is for minute ;)."
    }
    ],
    "has_more": true,
    "quota_max": 10000,
    "quota_remaining": 9981
}
```

You can write some javascript of you want this to be in a different format.

This is live-data but you're only allowed a [certain amount of calls per day](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle). You either need to authenticate or register an app to get more quota.

Comment: So, you've upgraded from SEDE to API? :D

Answer (score 3):

On your profile page, there is a [list of your comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/286598/sha-t?tab=activity&sort=comments).

I made a userscript as part of [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38285/display-the-number-of-comment-upvotes-in-recent-activity-pages/252985#252985) which shows the score of those comments as well - it does kind of what you want (shows the score of your comments), but it is not ordered and cannot be searched. However, if you know which comment you want to check, or just want an overall glance at their scores, this works :)

It looks like:[image]

You can get it from my [SE Additional Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) at StackApps.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such option because comments are temporary and can be deleted once sorted out.

Apart from humorous ones, all comments that add to the value of a post are supposed to be incorporated *into* the post itself to avoid noise. Comments are not meant to hold viewpoints that can be up or down voted. Voting on them is just to show whether a point raised is valid. Once valid, action is taken and the comment becomes obsolete.

And ofcourse, humorous comments tend to gather the most votes, so your search might not be too helpful.