# Display votes next to comments in User → All Actions → Comments tab

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page, comment-voting

Just as the number of votes is displayed next to an **answer** in the *Answers* tab (`https://site.stackexchange.com/users/userid/?tab=answers`), can we also have the number of votes displayed next to a **comment** in the *All Actions* → *Comments* tab (`https://site.stackexchange.com/users/userid/?tab=activity&sort=comments`)?

It will be useful to do self-learning / monitoring of which comments have been useful to the community, since upvote for a comment does *not* result in a message in the inbox (unlike an answer upvote which results in both a message and a reputation tab highlight).

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. Unfortunately, it has been requested before, at [Display the Number of Comment Upvotes In Recent Activity Pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38285/display-the-number-of-comment-upvotes-in-recent-activity-pages). For tips on how to get attention for that request, please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](/a/306398).

Comment: One of the answers to the previous suggestion contains a user script which you can use to get this in the meantime.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog  Thanks for the "attention for old request" answer link (I'm a newbie for meta).  The user script is a nice workaround, although it would be nice to have the feature request implemented.